# assign value of enum to struct?

Tags: c, struct, enums

Hi so I have this code but it says I can't use the enum in the for loop... and I dont know why.
Can someone help ? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum kuloer {spar, kloer, rudder, hjerte} kuloer;
typedef enum vaerdi {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, knaegt, dronning, konge} vaerdi;

typedef struct kort
{
   kuloer k;
   vaerdi v;
} kort;

int main(void){
   int i; 

   kort kort[52];

   for (i = 0; i < 52; i++)
   {
       kort[i].k = kuloer[i % 4];
       kort[i].v = vaerdi[i % 13];

       printf("Kort %d %c", i , kort[i].k);
       printf("Kort %d %c", i , kort[i].v);
   }
   
   

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerations doesn't work like variables. The name `kuloer` is a *type* alias. Also, enumeration defines a set of named integer constants, nothing else.

With that said, because enumerations are just named integer constants, you can use any integer value really, and treat it as an enumeration value. So e.g.

```
kort[i].k = i % 4;
```

will work fine.